# Why has this bound knockout element become undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Building a page using TypeScript and Knockout. When the page loads, the viewmodel creates and assigns a value to a "vehicles" array of objects.

```
vehicles: KnockoutObservableArray<Vehicle>;

constructor() {
    // uses and API to fetch data into a "vehicleData" array
    this.vehicles = ko.observableArray(vehicleData);
}
```

And in the page itself this is bound to an element which includes a "remove" button:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: vehicles">
    <div data-bind="text: model"></div>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeVehicle">Remove</button>
</div>
```

This is all fine. What I don't understand is what happens when removeVehicles in invoked. Here it is:

```
removeVehicle(vehicle): void {
    this.vehicles.remove(vehicle);
}
```

It passes in the parameter as expected, but when it tries to remove, it claims that "vehicles" no longer exists.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at Object.VehicleManagementViewModel.removeVehicle
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (knockout-latest.js:99)
```

What's caused the array to become undefined? How can it be undefined, when the HTML element is bound to it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference a function in your view model that way, `this` will be overriden by Knockout.

You can define the functions in your view model as arrow functions. This way, `this` will keep referencing the view model class.

So you can change:

```
removeVehicle(vehicle): void {
    this.vehicles.remove(vehicle);
}
```

To:

```
removeVehicle = (vehicle) => {
    this.vehicles.remove(vehicle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a knockout/typescript setup at hand to try this out, but i will take a guess and say that "this" has lost its reference to the parent class in the function.

If you look at an example on knockout home page, you can see that they use "self" variable to store "this" reference. Maybe the template doesnt call the function with correct "this" value. Use console.log to see what "this" value is.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: places">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removePlace">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function MyViewModel() {
         var self = this;
         self.places = ko.observableArray(['London', 'Paris', 'Tokyo']);

         // The current item will be passed as the first parameter, so we know which place to remove
         self.removePlace = function(place) {
             self.places.remove(place)
         }
     }
     ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```